# AuthorizedKeysCommand of sshd_config getting called twice

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, openssh

The `AuthorizedKeysCommand` parameter is present in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

The `bash` script I'm calling using this command is getting called twice.

The config file is as follows:

```
#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/a.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

And the `bash` script which is being called is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "have fun"
if [ $# -eq 1 ];
then
python /opt/validate_user.py $1
exit $?
fi
```

When i see the logs at `/var/log/messages`, I see the following

```
May 19 20:07:32 username vagrant: have fun
May 19 20:07:32 username vagrant: have fun
```

I am running Centos 6.7 and `ssh` version of the server is `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` and of the client is `OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011` and the command I'm using is `ssh -v vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`
Also when I do `vagrant ssh` then the script is called only once.

Edit: When i use the following command `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2200 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes  -i /Users/Vivek/new_file_1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key` then the script is getting called once only.
`ssh` log found using `ssh -vv`:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2200.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2200
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[127.0.0.1]:2200" from file "/Users/Vivek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/Vivek/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 125/256
debug2: bits set: 526/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA d2:10:e9:2e:60:59:8e:52:cd:f9:14:c3:45:fa:71:9d
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2200
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2200
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[127.0.0.1]:2200" from file "/Users/Vivek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/Vivek/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[127.0.0.1]:2200' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Vivek/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug2: bits set: 529/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fc920700000),
debug2: key: .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key (0x7fc920416de0),
debug2: key: /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:2200).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env COMMAND_MODE
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env ZSH
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Fri May 20 16:19:12 2016 from 10.0.2.2
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

Log of `/var/log/secure`: http://pastebin.com/BSk2j2Qf

Comment: 1) Server debug log will give you more clue when it is called. 2) Provide the log (`ssh -vvv host`), where you see it is called twice. I suspect you offer two different keys.

Comment: @Jakuje Added server debug log pastebin link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication to `ssh` server goes in two steps. The first one is validation if your public key is in the `authorized_keys` file (or output of the appropriate command), the second one checks if the signature provided by the appropriate private part is the same. In the server log, you can see:

```
sshd[9951]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
sshd[9950]: debug1: matching key found: file /opt/a.sh, line 1
sshd[9950]: Found matching RSA key: 8b:3c:20:c5:03:c4:c0:03:74:83:0a:8f:2d:d8:48:a2
sshd[9951]: Postponed publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 54361 ssh2
```

referring to the first occurrence (`test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable`). And later one

```
sshd[9950]: debug1: matching key found: file /opt/a.sh, line 1
sshd[9950]: Found matching RSA key: 8b:3c:20:c5:03:c4:c0:03:74:83:0a:8f:2d:d8:48:a2
sshd[9950]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 54361 ssh2
sshd[9950]: debug3: mm_answer_keyverify: key 0x7f54ce6ac570 signature verified
```

is checking the real signature made by the private part of the key.

**And why does it behave different if you specify the key on command line?** If openssh see only one identity, that is enforced by `IdentitiesOnly` option, it skips the first part and does only the second (if there are no more possibilities, what is the point of trying the first check?).

Comment: Does this happen in the case of AuthorizedKeysFile also ?

Comment: Yes. This is how the SSH authentication works. You can verify it again by checking server debug log.